# strcmp vs. == vs. === in PHP for checking hash equality

Tags: php, string, security, bcrypt, crypt

I'm using `crypt()` to hash passwords in PHP, and am trying to work out the safest way of testing equality of the resulting hash when performing password checks.

There are three options that I can see:

**Option 1 - Double Equals**

```
function checkPassword($hash, $password)
{
    return crypt($password, $hash) == $hash;
}
```

**Option 2 - Triple Equals**

```
function checkPassword($hash, $password)
{
    return crypt($password, $hash) === $hash;
}
```

**Option 3 - `strcmp()`**

```
function checkPassword($hash, $password)
{
    return strcmp(crypt($password, $hash), $hash) === 0;
}
```

My intuition tells me that option 1 is a bad idea, due to the lack of type checking, and that options 2 or 3 are likely to be better. However, I can't work out if there's a specific case that `===` or `strcmp` would fail under. Which is safest for this purpose?

Comment: Read it: http://raz0r.name/vulnerabilities/simple-machines-forum/

Comment: @Userpassword Interesting bug! I wonder how PHP handles strings like `$2a$10$...$` when cast as numbers...

Comment: If you just want to compare hashes reliably, simply use `===`. If you really care about security and potential timing attacks (even despite of network jitter), you should take a look at [this](https://github.com/delight-im/Faceless/issues/4) or [this](https://github.com/delight-im/Faceless/pull/5) discussion or use the `hash_equals()` function (PHP 5.6+).

Comment: check http://danuxx.blogspot.com/2013/03/unauthorized-access-bypassing-php-strcmp.html

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When it comes to security I prefer to use the `===` operator. `===` ensures the two operands are exactly the same, without trying to accomodate some casting in order to "help" the comparison to reach a successful match - as it may help while developing thanks to a loose-typed language, like PHP.

Of course, one of the operand is to be trusted. A hash from the database is trustable, while the user input is not.

One can always dither for a while, coming to the conclusion there is no risk using `==` in a specific case. Maybe. But for instance

```
  "0afd9f7b678fdefca" == 0 is true
  "aafd9f7b678fdefca" == 0 is also true
```

as PHP tries to convert the "hash" into a number (probably using *atoi*) which gives 0. While it is unlikely `crypt` returns 0, I'd prefer to maximize the cases where the passwords don't match (and answer a support call) by using `===`, than allowing a rare case that I didn't think about by using `==`.

As for `strcmp`, the function returns `<0` or `>0` if different, and 0 if equal. But

```
  strcmp("3", 0003) returns 0
  strcmp("0003", 0003) returns -3
```

which are not surprising after all. A literal `0003` is actually an integer, `3` and since *strcmp* expects a string, the `3` will be converted to `"3"`. But that shows there is some conversion that may happen in this case, since *strcmp* is a function, while `===` is part of the language.

So my preference in that case goes to `===` (which is faster than `==` anyway).

Comment: This is the most sensible answer I've seen. I agree that both type and value are important to avoid issues with the "cast helper".

Comment: Note that [hash_equals() should be used](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27066499/978756) when testing hash values produced with a strong function like `password_hash`.

Answer (score 8):

You should be using the hash_equals() function that is built into PHP. There would be no need to make your own function. The hash_equals() will return a boolean value.

In my opinion it is usually NOT a good idea to use == or === for comparing strings let alone hashed strings.

Comment: This is now the correct answer for values generated by `password_hash`, but `hash_equals` didn't exist in mainstream PHP at the time of asking, and it doesn't apply to flat hashes (which shouldn't be used anyway but are sometimes required for legacy)

Answer (score 0):

That is incorrect, please look at the definition of the function.
According to PHP:

`Returns < 0 if str1 is less than str2;`

`> 0 if str1 is greater than str2,`

`and 0 if they are equal`

It returns less than 0 if str1 is less than str2. Note the phrase "less than", it does not return just -1, but any negative value. The same happens when str1 is greater than str2, but it returns a positive, non-zero value. It returns a positive value that can be 1, or any number thereafter.

`strcmp()`returns a number that is the difference between the two strings starting with the last character that was found to be similar.

Here is an example:

`$output = strcmp("red", "blue");`

The variable $output with contain a value of 16

Answer (score -5):

I think that using `==` would be sufficient in your case.

`==` checks for equality regardless of type, whereas `===` checks for equality as well as type.

`1 == "1"` = True

`1 === "1"` = False

Since we're not too concerned with type, I'd keep it simple and go with `==`.

Comment: I'm aware of the differences between `==` and `===`, but I'm trying to work out if there's a specific security-sensitive case that I'm missing. For example, is there a reason *not* to use `strcmp`?

Comment: Since you're not concerned with a binary safe comparison, I wouldn't use strcmp. You're not concerned with how different the strings are -- you're just concerned with whether or not they are semantically the same.

Comment: What if `bcrypt` fails for some reason? Might it be possible for a non-string return value to be considered equal to a string value for `$hash`, where that variable is a valid hash?

Comment: In short, no. It should not make any different.

Comment: $hash = function_returing_0();
var_dump(('00somehash' == $test));
returns true so using only double == without a string cast is a security hole..

Comment: Well, then the question becomes "Can $hash be zero?", or .. Where does  $hash come from?

Comment: @gries In this case the hashes will always start with `$2a$10` so I *think* we can discount that issue, but it pays to be safe.

Comment: yeay as long as the hash algorithm does not change, and I'm sure if this is the case no one will notice the problem with comparing == without a cast

Comment: if( "asdf" == 0 )
        die("d'oh\n");

Comment: @IanP no thats not the question, he needs a function that securly compares 2 strings, we should NOT care about what the strings "should" or "may" look like, because these things can change